# SUMIFS with moving criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs

My excel worksheet looks something like this:

Worksheet:

[image]

What I would like to do is to sum all of Bob's X1 values that are larger than the X2, X3 and X4 values on their respective row. So, in this case, 5 + 14 + 15 = 34, as the other X1 values of Bob (1, 6, -5 and 0) are smaller than the X2, X3 or X4 values on the same row with them.

I have tried this:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B11,A2:A11,"Bob",B2:B11,MAX(B2:E2))
```

But this will simply take the X1 value on each row, and instead of comparing it with the X2-4 values on its row, it will of course compare it with the X2-4 values on the first row, which is not what I want. I have also tried some other formulas, using arrays and OFFSET, but I have in no way been able to "synchronize" the X1 value with its respective row.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This should work with an array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+RETURN).

```
{=SUM(IF(A2:A11="Bob",1,0)*IF(C2:C11<B2:B11,1,0)*IF(D2:D11<B2:B11,1,0)*IF(E2:E11<B2:B11,1,0)*B2:B11)}
```

This would calculate the product inside the `SUM` function for each of the rows individually and then calculate the sum of those products.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

> =SUM(IF(A2:A11="Bob",IF(B2:B11>=C2:C11,IF(B2:B11>=D2:D11,IF(B2:B11>=E2:E11,B2:B11)))))

Enter as an array formula, using CTRL, SHIFT and ENTER. Curly brackets will appear round the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why does everyone seem so keen to use array formulas?
Here is a solution that avoids them:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$11*($A$2:$A$11="Bob")*($B$2:$B$11>$C$2:$C$11)*($B$2:$B$11>$D$2:$D$11)*($B$2:$B$11>$E$2:$E$11))
```

Just multiply the range you want to sum by each of your criteria, within a SUMPRODUCT.

[image]